# Call Rally Excel plug in procedures from Excel VBA

Tags: rally

I want to use the Rally Excel Plugin, to do some company wide reporting. This entails pulling out the same information from multiple Workspaces/Projects.

Ideally, I'd be able to use vba to select the workspace and project I want, refresh all the queries, take the data I need then move on to the next one and repeat until I done this for all the projects I wanted.

Is there anyway of calling the procedures in the Rally Excel Plug in using VBA?

From reading around I *think* I would need to know the library names and arguments from the dll and then declare them at the start of my module, but not really sure how to get that information.

Answer (score 0):

The [add-ins user guide](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide#Usage) does not mention calling procedures. Once the data was exported from Rally to Excel, it is a spreadsheet at this point, and macros can be applied, but there is no guidance on that in the add-in's documentation.

There is unsupported [Rally Rest Toolkit for VBA](https://github.com/markwilliams970/RallyRestToolkitForVBA). The addin itself was written with a branch of [Rally Rest Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Nick's answer, the Excel plugin sports a nice Excel-based UI around the [Rally REST Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET). Ideally, the best approach would be to load the [REST .NET DLL](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/releases/download/v2.0.1/rally-rest-api.net-2.0.1.zip) into Excel and call its methods via VBA.

However, in order for VBA to be able to access the public methods in a DLL, the DLL has to have COM-visible methods. So, in order to make this work, one would need to:

1. Fork Rally REST .net
2. Write some COM wrappers around the public methods in REST.NET
3. Re-compile the project into a custom REST .NET DLL

There are some online resources that discuss this process:

http://jumbloid.blogspot.com/2009/12/making-net-dll-com-visible.html

However, I'm not an expert in the techniques used, and this would have the downside of a forked version of the DLL.

Nonetheless, using methods exposed in the DLL would be more robust and a lot faster (multi-threaded) than the VBA/ActiveX experiment in REST from pure VBA outlined in the Rally REST Toolkit for VBA that Nick references above.